# Laravel 8 "Queue::push" is working, but "dispatch" is not

Tags: queue, push, laravel-8, jobs, dispatch

I'm facing an issue with Laravel queued jobs.
I'm using Laravel v8.40.0 with Redis v6.2.5 and Horizon v5.7.14 for managing jobs.

I have a job class called MyJob which should write a message in log file.
If I use `Queue::push(new MyJob())` everything seems to work fine: I see the job in Horizon and the new row in log file.

But if I use `dispatch(new MyJob())` or `MyJob::dispatch()` it doesn't seem to push my job into queue: I can't see the job in Horizon and I see no results in log file.

I was following the docs (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#dispatching-jobs) to use queues correctly and I don't understand where I'm doing wrong.

Thank you